# JSON like Javascript Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sure someone has already asked these things before but I am seriously not able to find that thread.

I have written something like below, but I dont know the name of this kind of structure in javascript, lets assume its name is like (Javascript in JSON Structure).

I need to know number of things for this kind of structure,
1) What is its actual name, if any?
2) how to get variables at parent.parent level in this structure, like in SentenceBuilder.Section.get function I need to get SentenceBuilder.get function, I have tried this.this.get but it will not work.
3) What is best way to declare private variables in this structure which can only be used within its functions. I have tried _sentenceBuilder: new Object(), is it OK?

Thank you so much in advance...

```
var SentenceBuilder = {
    _sentenceBuilder: new Object(),
    _section: new Object(),
    _group: new Object(),
    _question: new Object(),

    get: function () {
        return this._sentenceBuilder;  //for speeding up;  --wasim
        //return store.fetchSession("SENTENCE_BUILDER_" + VisitID);        
    },
    set: function () {
        store.saveSession("SENTENCE_BUILDER_" + VisitID, data);
        this._sentenceBuilder = $(data);
    },
    Section: {
        get: function () {

            this.this._section = this.this.get().find("SECTION[SECTION_SEQ_NUM='" + sectionID + "']");
            return this.this._section;
        },
        set: function () { },
    },
    Group: {
        get: function () {
            this.this._group = this.this.Section.get().find("GROUP[QUESTION_GROUP_ID='" + groupID + "']");
            if (this.this._group.length == 0) {
                this.this._question = this.this.Section.get().find("QUESTION[QUESTION_ID='" + questionID + "']");
                this.this._group = this.this._question.parent();
            }
            return this.this._group;
        },
        set: function () { }

    },
    Question: {
        get: function () {
            this.this._question = this.this._group.find("QUESTION[QUESTION_ID='" + qId + "']");
            return this._question;
        },
        set: function () { }

    }
};
```

Comment: you cannot do `this.this` ... and take a look at this article http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you are asking about the Module Pattern or not but the module pattern look like the following:

```
//Single Global Variable "Module"
var Module = ( function ( ) {
 var privateVariable = "some value",
    privateMethod = function ( ) {
        //do something.
 };
//returning one anonymous object literal that would expose privileged methods.
 return {
     //the method inside the return object are 
     //called as privileged method because it has access 
     //to the private methods and variables of the module.

     privilegedMethod : function ( ) {
        //this method can access its private variable and method 
        //by using the principle of closure. 
        alert(privateVariable); //accessing private variable.
        privateMethod( ); //calling private method
    }
 };
})( );
```

Here Module is the Single Global Variable that is exposed to the document. We are declaring, calling one anonymous method and assigning it to Module variable.

Now we can call privilegedMethod by writing `Module.privilegedMethod();` internally privileged Method of module can access its private variable and private method. Because, they come under their static scope. If we have any data or method that we don't want to expose, we can put them in private methods.

For complete details please read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247241/Javascript-Module-Pattern

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is its actual name, if any?

It's an object, just a plain old object.

> 2) how to get variables at parent.parent level in this structure, like in SentenceBuilder.Section.get function I need to get SentenceBuilder.get function, I have tried this.this.get but it will not work.

You can't navigate "up" objects like that. To access `SentenceBuilder.Section.get`, you would literally have to type `SentenceBuilder.Section.get`, or start manually storing `parent` variables so that each object has a reference to its parent

> 3) What is best way to declare private variables in this structure which can only be used within its functions. I have tried _sentenceBuilder: new Object(), is it OK?

Yes, that's pretty common, though it's private only by *convention*. If you want truly private variables, you need to use closures. Put your object in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and return it:

```
var SentenceBuilder = (function () {

  var sentenceBuilder: new Object(),
  var section: new Object(),
  var group: new Object(),
  var question: new Object(),

  var SentenceBuilder = {
    // above variables can be accessed here...
    // ...
  };

  return SentenceBuilder;
})();

// ... but not here or anywhere else
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's an Object-Literal
   It's "literal", because its public interface is exactly what you type in (plus things inherited by all objects/functions/strings).

   ```
   var bob = {
       name : "Bob",
       age  : 32,
       getName : function () { return this.name; },
       getAge  : function () { return bob.age;   }
   };
   ```
2. I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  But JS objects have **no** way of getting their parent-object, unless you manually set it.
   The simple reason for this is because you can do this

   ```
   var stewie = {
       name : "Stewie",
       size : "small"
   },

   peter = {
       name : "Peter",
       size : "large",
       child : stewie
   },

   lois = {
       name : "Lois",
       size : "average",
       child : stewie
   };

   peter.child === lois.child; // true

   stewie.parent; // what would this be?

   //manually store a reference to parent
    var parent_object = {
           data : "",
           child_object : {
               data : "",
               parent : parent_object
           }
       };

    parent_object.child_object.parent === parent_object;  //true
   ```
3. There is no such thing as a private property/method on an Object-Literal.
   If you want a private property, then you should use a `function` (not necessarily a constructor), and return a public interface from it.

   ```
   var my_object = (function () {
       var my_secret = 42, // private
           data = { },     // private
           validate = function (guess) { return guess === my_secret; }, // private

           guess_secret = function (guess) {
               return validate(guess) ? data : null;
           },

           public_interface = {
               secret : {
                   owner : public_interface,
                   guess : guess_secret
               }
           };

       return public_interface;
   }());


   my_object.my_secret;  // undefined
   my_object.validate(); // error

   var secret_data = my_object.secret.guess(42);
   ```

Comment: It's only an object *literal* so long as you're talking about the source code. When you start talking about not being able to have private properties/methods on an "object literal", you should be dropping the "literal": You cannot have private properties/members on *objects*.

Comment: @meagar I'm not going to argue that point, except to say that any other form of object-construction, including returning literals from inside another function's scope, offer what Crockford referred to as "privileged" methods. Or, in line with bridging the mental-spaces between Java/C# and JS, public methods which retain access to private state/processes. Objects which are literal in creation, without IIFEs, have no access to such a feature. Even old-school straight function constructors offered privacy (don't attach everything to `this`, and write getters/continuations to bridge prototypes)

Comment: An object literal is an object literal regardless of whether it's contained in a function or not. Closures don't enter into it.

Comment: @meagar ...yes, and an inline initialization of an object (ie: "literal") has no option to access enclosed scope (separate from the scope it was assigned in), which directly differs from all other initialization a methods, and thus, to do so, you abstract the initialization into a separate scope, which does, then allow for access to enclosed variables. It's easy to pedantly say "no object has private state", but that's just not true in a practical application, or callbacks would require Java-like classes, et cetera.

Comment: No object has private state. Closures may include variables that become inaccessible outside that function, but that isn't relevant to *objects*. Objects don't close over variables, functions do.

Comment: @meagar And yet, in a Java/C# world, the expectation is that if an object has private (members|properties)/methods, that public methods have access to that private state.  Inline objects can define object properties and object methods, and yet, there is no potential for internal-state.

Comment: @meagar and given that he's asking expressly about dealing with conventions for accessing/modifying private-state, whilst using methods of an object, I feel that this is a ***very*** important distinction to be made.